# Prism : executing action before command is called

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I have a button with an updateCommand that saves current workspace so i need to retrieve it before updateCommand is called to pass current workspace as a commandparameter.

Seems itemclick event begins before command but when i tried to access to the parameter i obtained null values.

Which is it the correct procedure to process some 'view' actions, retrieve information and pass it to a commandParameter in a MVVM prism manner.

Comment: why do you need an action an cannot handle everything in your command?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use both the ItemClick code-behind method and a Command. Don't use the Click event. All the data your Command needs to work with should already be available in the ViewModel.